# Replace NaN with existing values proportionately

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let us say I have a Dataframe which has a column `Quality`, with values `[Poor, Average, Good, Excellent]`.

The frame has 120 values out of which 20 are `NaN` and the rest 100 have 20, 30, 40, 10 each of `[Poor, Average, Good, Excellent]`.

Is there any easy way to replace the 20 `NaN` rows with values from `[Poor, Average, Good, Excellent]` such that the proportion of the overall frame remains at 20% Poor, 30% Average, 40% Good and 10% Excellent, using Python, Pandas and NumPy?

The idea is to retain the original proportion after filling the `NaN` irrespective of the size of the dataset.

Comment: Do you need it to be exactly the same percentage, or just statistically the same? If the latter is okay, you can just use `np.random_choice` to generate a list, with the length given by the # of null values, and the distribution of values given by your non-null values.

Comment: @ALollz, can you illustrate with a code sample please? I am slightly new to Pandas and Python in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is an easier way to do it, I wrote this function to achieve what I wanted.

```
def replace_with_proportion(frame, column):
     isnull = frame[column].isnull()
     sample = frame[column].dropna()
     sample=set(sample)
     countframe=pd.DataFrame(columns=["name", "count", "proportion"])
     for x in sample:
          countframe.loc[-1] = [x,frame.loc[frame[column] == x].shape[0], 0 ]
          countframe.index = countframe.index + 1
     countframe['proportion']=countframe['count']/countframe['count'].sum()
     to_fill=np.random.choice(countframe['name'], size=(frame[column].isnull().sum(),), p=countframe['proportion'])
     frame.loc[isnull, column] = to_fill
     return frame
```